# Expiration timer

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a record in my Android DB which is saved along with its creation time. I want to have a  timer where after 2 hours this item will be deleted. I researched it and I came to two results:

one was to make an AsyncTask, but this solution seems to me like it would take too many resources without any need.

the second was to implement a Service. I know nothing of Services in Android and how they work. I made some reading and I don't see how I can have a service counting time and checking if it has exceeded its lifespan.

Halp plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that `"CountDownTimer" works well as long as your application is alive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could give a look into the `AlarmManager` Class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply ignore Rows that are older than 2hours? Simply create a VIEW on your Table. Paired with an INSERT/UPDATE Trigger on the DB that delete old Records.

pseudo:
for the view select

```
select * from table where createdate > now()-2hours


create trigger on table.cleanuptrigger after insert/update 

on table for each row when createdate < now()-2hours;
```